# jQuery is not defined, $ is not defined and Cannot read property 'fn'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, jplayer

I am making a web application for a university project. This is about music, until I could upload the music easily, but when I am going to reproduce I have several problems, which I have been looking for and have not been able to solve yet.
Mainly when I inspect my page I always get the jQuery error not defined, and the moment a song to play it, I get the $ is not defined error. But when I load the page at that point and let me play the songs, and I can go and play the next one normally. But whenever I start section and try to play them at the beginning never works. And it is always necessary to reload the page to make it work normally.

this is the head of the html:

```html
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <Script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
          ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
              mp3: "<%=@article.mp3.url%>"
            });
          },
          swfPath: "/js",
          wmode: "window",
          supplied: "mp3",
          useStateClassSkin: true,
          autoBlur: false,
          smoothPlayBar: true,
          keyEnabled: true,
          remainingDuration: true,
          toggleDuration: true
        });
      });
    </script>
</head>
```

for this moment i have a the `<%=render "reload"%>` in the first line of the html. Because before I had to load the page every time I went to review a song. With this I do not have to do it. But I still have the problem mentioned above.
this is the _reload:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
         location.reload();
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: if you view the developer tools network tab when you load the page, is `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js` loaded without error?

Comment: Put `<%=render "reload"%>` after loading jQuery script.

Comment: Also, why not `https://code.jquery....`? Always use https if available. Because if Your websites have SSL enabled, then jQuery script will be blocked if You use http protocol.

Comment: yes that loaded well in the page. and when I put the <%=render "reload"%> This starts loading the page countless times

Comment: @instead - Personally, I'd use `//code.jquery...` wherever applicable, (i.e. if the resource is available http and https)

Comment: I added https and the error remains the same

Comment: Your second script is `<Script>` not `<script>`.

Comment: @lscmaro HTML tags are case-insensitive

Comment: Make sure you're not loading jquery multiple times. Also check for calls to `jQuery.noConflict()`.

Comment: What happens if you change all the `$` to `jQuery`

Comment: this happened VM2382:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at <anonymous>:2:5

Comment: Try moving your code to the body, but leave pulling jQuery in the head.

Comment: @JaromandaX `//some.url` is an old practice. Loading https resources on http website is ok, and https on https seems to be logical.

Comment: @Barmar it was an observation in clean coding rather than an answer. I hope you don't HTML in all CAPS! :)
@JoseSanchez  - I'd try moving the `$(document).ready()` just before the closing element `</body>` and see if that works. You might be facing a race condition

Comment: @lscmaro I tried that, but it still has the same problem. This only happens when I start section. When I hear the song I get the error. But I charge the page and it works. I think that when I start section, the jquery is not loading. Because every time I close the section and restart I have the same error. I always have to reload the page in the beginning, and then it already works fine.

Comment: Start simple and comment out all your code inside the `$(document).ready()` then just add a `console.log('ready')` inside. just to even see if that works. If that works then you're either missing needed information here or it must deal with your jplayer.js. Also according to the plugin page http://jplayer.org/latest/quick-start-guide/step-2/ they reference jQuery 1.11.1 . That version you have may be an issue with this plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plugin page shows you're missing a little information in this post. A link to a css file, ex:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jplayer/2.9.2/skin/pink.flag/css/jplayer.pink.flag.min.css">
```

Here's a codepen of your plugin working as intended. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eEGbXG

It uses the referenced jQuery version 1.11.1 and the plugins' CDN links for style and js, which you can also find here: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jplayer

I used your same markup and commented out your jPlayer function and it works as well.

I added the example markup in the body referenced from your plugin page from here also: http://jplayer.org/latest/quick-start-guide/step-6-audio/

Hope this helps!